# take variable in outer function in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

I need help getting the `$total` variable into `return $seed = ( rand('1','10') * $seed + 5) % $this->total;`. Can anyone help me?

```
public function index()
{       
    $total = $this->m_soal->count_soal();
    

    function lcm_rand($seed) {
        return function() use (& $seed ) {

            return $seed = ( rand('1','10') * $seed + 5) % $this->total;
        };
    }
     
}
```

Comment: can you please add your full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would need the inner function, but perhaps something like this would help you.

```php
private int $total = 5; // for testing purposes

public function lcm_rand($seed)
{
    return ((random_int(1, 10) * $seed) + 5) % $this->total;
}
```